# Minimum number of $|\cdot|$ operations necessary to express $\max$

Tags: co.combinatorics, real-analysis

For two variables, their maximum
$\max\{x_1,x_2\}$ can be expressed using one  $|\cdot|$ operation:
$$
\max\{x_1,x_2\} = \frac12(x_1+x_2+|x_1-x_2|).
$$
For $3$ variables, it seems fairly clear that three $|\cdot|$ operations are necessary, though I can only demonstrate sufficiency:
$$
\max\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}
=
\frac14\left[
2x_1+x_2+x_3+|x_2-x_3|+2\left|x_1-\frac12(x_2+x_3+|x_2-x_3|)\right|
\right]
.
$$
For $5$ variables, it has been claimed here
https://twitter.com/ereliuer_eteer/status/1669081421007454209
that the minimum number of
$|\cdot|$ operations is 54, though I have verified neither sufficiency nor necessity.

Question: How many $|\cdot|$ operations are necessary for $n$ variables?
To be explicit about the rules, in addition to $|\cdot|$, the 4 arithmetic operations are allowed.

Update. That twitter post I linked is actually computing the median, not the max of 5 variables. So the analogous question for abs-operation complexity, but now for the median, is quite natural.

Comment: Evidently you get some kind of bound using the fact that $\max (x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \max(x_1, \max(x_2,\ldots,x_n))$.

Comment: Sure, that would give an exponential upper bound -- right?

Comment: I guess $\lfloor \log n \rfloor$ is a weak lowerbound from information theoretic considerations.

Comment: @TonyHuynh If we are allowed just linear forms and absolute value, the trivial lower bound is $n-1$. Otherwise, we can keep all absolute values at $0$ and obtain a 2-dimensional subspace on which the maximum is a linear function, which is absurd.

Comment: @fedja’s $n-1$ lower bound holds even if we consider circuit size rather than formula size. For circuit size, it is tight, as the recurrence in Sam Hopkins comment gives a circuit using linear forms and $n-1$ absolute values.

Comment: @TonyHuynh Could you please provide some details for the information theoretic argument you had in mind?

Comment: @SaliniMendisi I don't really see the pont since fedja has already given a beautiful argument that gives a better bound.  Here goes though.  If there are fewer than  $\log(n)$ absolute values, then there exist polyhedra $P_1, \dots, P_\ell$ such that $\ell < n$ and the expression is an affine function on each $P_i$.  Then we get a similar contradiction as fedja, since by pigeonhole we may assume that the set of points $(x_1, x_2, 0, \dots, 0)$, such that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are sufficiently large are contained in the same $P_j$.  However, this is clearly impossible.

Comment: @TonyHuynh I asked because fedja's argument assumed one doesn't use multiplication and division, and I thought yours doesn't need that assumption

Comment: My argument doesn't really need that, but I don't think fedja really needs it either.  As long as the function "without absolute values" cannot express the max function on a 2-dimensional subspace, fedja's argument seems to work.  This is true for a lot of functions.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Let $f(k)$ be the minimum number of $|\cdot|$ operations to express the maximum of $2^k$ variables. Using the identities
$$\max\{x_1,x_2\} = (x_1+x_2+|x_1-x_2|)/2,$$
$$\max\{x_1,\ldots,x_{2^{k+1}}\} = 
\max\{\max\{x_1,\ldots,x_{2^k}\},\max\{x_{2^k+1},\ldots,x_{2^{k+1}}\}\},$$
it is clear that $f(1)=1$ and $f(k+1)\leq 4f(k)+1$. Hence it follows by induction that
$$f(k)\leq (4^k-1)/3.$$
Now let us consider the case of $n$ variables. If $2^{k-1}<n\leq 2^k$, then the minimal number of corresponding $|\cdot|$ operations is less than $4^k/3$, which is less than $(4/3)n^2$.

**Added.** In fact that minimal number of $|\cdot|$ operations is less than $(3/8)n^2$. For details, see AspiringMat's response and the comments below it.

Comment: Very nice! Can you prove that the minimal number of abs operations is $\Omega(n^2)$?

Comment: @AryehKontorovich What's best lower bound you know?

Comment: In particular, $(4/3)5^2=100/3< 34 < 54$.

Comment: In particular by splitting 5 into 2 and 3 items, we have $g(5) \le 2*g(2) + 2*g(3) + 1 \le 2 + 6 + 1$, where $g(n)$ is the minimal number of abs operations on $n$ items

Comment: @mathworker21  Tony Huynh suggested $\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor$ based on information-theoretic considerations. I actually don't think a lower bound of $\Omega(n^2)$ holds. Since $\max$ is computable in a linear number of pairwise comparisons, I would expect something like $O(n)$ to be the truth.

Comment: @AryehKontorovich But there is often a gap between minimum formula size and minimum circuit size. Do you have an example that beats the upper bound given in [AspiringMat's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/448924)?

Comment: @TimothyChow no, I don't have any such examples.

Answer (score 15):

This is just a tighter analysis of the analysis from @GH from MO.

Let $f(n)$ be the minimum number of $|\cdot|$ operations to compute $\max(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$. Then $f(1)=0$ and for $n\geq 1$:

$$f(n)\leq 1+2\min_{1\leq j < n}\left( f(j)+f(n-j)\right)$$

Generating the first few values, we get for $n\geq 2$: $1, 3, 5, 9, 13, 17, \ldots$ which plugging into OEIS give [this sequence](https://oeis.org/search?q=%201%2C%203%2C%205%2C%209%2C%2013%2C%2017%2C%2021%2C%2029%2C%2037%2C%2045%2C%2053%2C%2061%2C%2069%2C%2077%2C%2085&language=english&go=Search) (Shifted by 2). Plugging in, we get

$$f(n) \leq  n 2^{\lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor } - \frac{2\cdot 4^{\lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor} + 1}{3}$$

In the notes, it says that this is the solution to the recurrence $$a(n)=1+2a(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor)+2a(\lceil n/2 \rceil) $$ which suggests that the minimization above happens precisely at $j=\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$.

The upper bound behaves like $1/3 n^2$. Comparing the upper bound above and $4/3 n^2$, we get:

[image]

One interesting note is that if we consider the DP

$$f(n)\leq \min_{i,j | 0\leq i+j <n }3+2f(i)+4f(j)+4f(n-i-j)$$

Which uses the second identity in OP's answer ($x_1$ appears twice, and $x_2, x_3$ appear 4 times, with $3$ extra $|\cdot|$), then it seems to be minimized at precisely the same minima as the 2D case. It would be interesting if there are alternative expressions for $n=3$ that use less variables which can be used to get better bounds.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Few typos, fixed now.

Comment: @TimothyChow yes you're right, edited.

Comment: The bound is about $\frac13n^2$ when $n$ is close to a power of $2$, but it gets up to about $\frac38n^2$ when $n\sim\frac432^k$.

Comment: The reason the 3-variable DP is not any better is that it follows from the 2-variable DP: $f(x+y+z) \le 2f(x) + 2f(y+z) + 1 \le 2f(x) + 4f(y) + 4f(z) + 3$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Ahh, not so interesting after all :).

Comment: Two comments. First, the quoted formula for $a(n)$ is easy to prove by induction. One needs to distinguish between $n$ even and $n$ odd, and in the odd case one needs to treat $n=2^k−1$ separately. Second, it is straightforward to verify that $a(n)$ lies between $\frac{1}{3}n^2-\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{3}{8}n^2-\frac{3}{8}$.

Comment: Can there even be other formulas other than those made from a max of a max of each part in a partition of a set? (not including boring manipulation, like adding and subtracting the same thing, multiplying inside absolute value by a constant and dividing outside and so on)

Comment: Eh, I missed that $\max\{x_1,x_2\} = x_1 + x_2 - \min\{x_1,x_2\}  =  x_1 + x_2 + \max\{-x_1,-x_2\}$ and there is probably something similar in more variables.